# Locally throw exception and handle it

Tags: exceptions

I came across a piece of legacy code, almost on the line of this ([sample](https://godbolt.org/z/ab9Yxr77d))

```
int foo() {
    try {
        int id = generateID();
        if (isIDUsed(id)) throw id;
        return id;
    } catch (int id) {
        std::cerr << "exception: Used Event ID Generated" << id << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here `generateID()` and `isIDUsed()` doen't throw any exceptions, and yes, the code doesn't return a value from the `catch` clause branch too. I would have instead preferred something like

```
int foo() {
    int id = generateID();
    if (isIDUsed(id)) {
        std::cerr << "Used Event ID Generated" << id << '\n';
        return -1; // id can never be -1, so it's fine to use this sentinel value
    }
    return id;
}
```

What are the benefits of using the former approach of coding, if any, where we throw an exception and handle it locally?

Comment: @PhilipKendall It's not supposed to. It's to demonstrate a piece of code on which I'm seeking an opinion.

Comment: @PhilipKendall And yes, it doesn't return a value from the function from the `catch` clause. That's _pretty much_ the exact piece of code that's there in the codebase :)

Comment: Well, code which doesn't compile is pretty clearly terrible.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Why doesn't it compile? It does throw a warning but it passes compilation. I guess you might have -Werror turned on? [Here's](https://godbolt.org/z/ab9Yxr77d) pretty much the same code that compiles. I've added the sample to the question too.

Comment: @PhilipKendall & Zoso: the example compiles on some C++ compilers, on some it doesn't

Comment: Thank you @DocBrown for that clarification. I'd hoped people can actually focus on the question rather than being pedantic in raising issues about compilable code but well...Only gnasher729 has thankfully attempted to look at my actual query. I'll probably delete the question since this platform doesn't seem to entertain asking questions anymore and never explain why people feel the question needs to be downvoted without suggesting improvements.

Comment: It's not unusual to find poorly-written exception code - there could be a million reasons for it, but it would not change the fact that the code is bad.    The best thing to do with legacy code is to avoid worrying about the original developer's motivations and focus instead on enshrining its functionality in automated tests (even if you suspect the functionality is wrong);   once automated tests exist, you can drastically reduce the risk of unintended consequences when refactoring, and the question of why the code was written in a particular way becomes irrelevant.

Comment: It looks like this earned most of it's poor reception before Zoso showed that this code compiles (on some compilers). I think with these edits it deserves a better reception.

Comment: @Zoso: the problem with this question is that it contains two unrelated issues (exceptions & the missing return statement). You probably wanted to ask only about the exceptions, but the missing return statement looks so offending for many others that they focussed on that. There would have been a simple solution for this, by just adding the missing return statement to the code by yourself. Please don't do that now, it would invalidate the existing answers, but next time you ask a question, keep in mind it is better to ask about *one* thing, not more.

Comment: @DocBrown I get your point and I'll take care of this going forward but I didn't change the code because I wasn't entirely sure if that had something to do with the way the code was written in the first snippet(I didn't think so but who knows...). I had tried to be clear about what I was asking about with the title but then... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you wrote I guess you are more interested in the differences of the two code snippets regarding exception handling. That comparison will only make sense when both do the same, with no undefined behaviour. Hence let us assume the first variant looks like this:

```
int foo() {
    try {
        int id = generateID();
        if (isIDUsed(id)) throw id;
        return id;
    } catch (int id) {
        std::cerr << "exception: Used Event ID Generated" << id << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Now the distracting nonsense of an undefined return code is fixed, and we can answer to your main question.

The actual difference (or maybe advantage) of this variant over the second is that, even when `generateID` or `isIDUsed` doesn't throw any exception **today**, the code will (probably) still work when those functions will be modified or overloaded **tomorrow** with a version which does.

That can specifically be useful in a context where `generateID` or `isIDUsed` are under maintenance responsibility by someone who is not responsible for the function `foo`. It makes not much sense, however, if all those three functions are part of the same class or module and none of them is declared as virtual. Then the construct would probably be overcomplicated and the second variant preferable.

Comment: "however, if all those three functions are part of the same class or module".     

That's exactly the case in my scenario!

Answer (score 8):

When you can get this to compile what it returns is undefined. Exceptions are meant to take you off the happy path and shouldn't return you to it without putting you in a recovered (well defined) state. Returning undefined garbage to the happy path is not a recovered state. No mater what you sent to std::cerr.

Reasonable options here include:

- returning a flag value (like -1), provided the happy path can deal with that or
- rethrowing (either the same exception or some new one) and

  - either recovering somewhere up the call stack or
  - letting the system halt

Whatever called `foo()` expected to get an ID out of it. If you rethrow then it needs to get caught somewhere free of that expectation.

One of the classic problems with languages that allow undefined behavior is that coders don't realize that it's happening. They run a test and expect they'll always get that same behavior. And for a while they do. Then someone changes the compiler, or the hardware, or Venus is in retrograde, and suddenly the behavior is different.

Now if we've fixed the undefined behavior in the first listing:

```
 int foo() {
    try {
        int id = generateID();
        if (isIDUsed(id)) throw id;
        return id;
    } catch (int id) {
        std::cerr << "exception: Used Event ID Generated" << id << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I'm still not happy. Because if `generateID()` or `isIDUsed()` ever do decide to throw you'd better hope they don't also decide to be weird and throw ints because this code is going to assume those were also  IDs. And since there is no stack trace (since you didn't build actual exceptions) you wont even log what threw the mysterious int.

If my only options are the two offered I prefer the second in any case. When things go wrong you don't have to always use exceptions. But if you use error flags please make sure to check for them. They're easy to forget.

Answer (score -1):

Being legacy code, it may be that generateID() used to throw exceptions. And possibly still does, and an extra check was added later. Your change would stop handling the exception. So you better check this.

Comment: My bad for not clarifying that in the question. `generateID()` doesn't throw any exceptions.